# How can I say "it's actually the opposite" in a single phrase?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

> "It's a bit confusing to talk about evolution as a process driven by randomness. In reverse, most of the processes​ we talk about in evolutionary biology can be described in strict mathematical formulas. The best way to think about it is to take them as the results of the probabilities of the actions on nature."

Which phrase can i replace the "in reverse" in the text to indicate that the reality is the opposite than the common belief holds.

Comment: I thought I had a good understanding of both English *and* evolution, but I can't see what you're getting at when you say the "truth" you're trying to convey represents the "reverse, opposite" of ***evolution is a process driven by randomness***. To my mind, the reverse of *A is driven by B* ought to be *B is driven by A*. In your context this amounts to ***randomness is driven by evolution***, which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: You could say "Actually, ..."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Haha, yeah that may be true. I meant opposite in sense of negation.

Comment: -1 for thinking that the idea here is simply *negation*.

Comment: @TRomano I think you missed the meaning. I don't want to express that "randomness is driven by evolution", that's why it's not "opposite" as in your definition but as "negation". Don't you think that the commonly held view on evolution as on a random process and the evolutionary theory where the process of evolution is an inevitable statistics of the population are incompatible?

Comment: Evolution is not relevant to the *language* question here,  You need a phrase which makes the necessary transition from the predicate of your first sentence to the predicate of your second sentence.

Comment: @TRomano Well I was trying to express the meaning in which are the sentences opposite. I don't know if you see another meaning in the paragraph, however this is what I wanted to say and if it doesn't say that, it's a mistake in my English skills. Yes, I wanted a phrase with the function of transition, however I specifically wanted it to express that the new theory stays the opposite view than the old theory did. I'm grateful for your help but, "to the contrary" is, I think, what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @TRomano Although, I'm not really sure now...[this site](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/1836032094) says "to the contrary" *can't* have the meaning of "in contrast", which seems to be close to what I was looking for.

Comment: @TRomano Also, I couldn't find any sentence where "to the contrary" would stay at the begining.

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is confusing.  I think you mean to say that it's *misleading* to talk about evolution as *purely* driven by randomness.  If you then follow up with any of these, the change in direction makes more sense:

> Actually, most of the processes ...
>
> In actuality, most of the processes ...
>
> The truth is, most of the processes ...
>
> It would be more accurate to say that most of the processes ...
>
> The reality is, most of the processes ...

as well as various other expressions.  Depending on your audience, you can even get a little creative, for example playing off your use of "driven" to use some automobile metaphors:

> Superficially, when we think of evolution, we imagine it driven purely by randomness and chance.  However, when we take a look *under the hood* we find that the engine driving evolution runs on a strict, well-defined set of mathematical formulas.

Comment: +1 Your emphasis on **purely** hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

The standard phrase in replace of "in reverse" would be **To the contrary**.

> "It's a bit confusing to talk about evolution as a process driven by randomness. **To the contrary**, most of the processes​ we talk about in evolutionary biology can be described in strict mathematical formulas. The best way to think about it is to take them as the results of the probabilities of the actions on nature."

It is [defined here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+contrary):

> as the opposite of what has been stated; contrary to what has been stated.

Comment: **to the contrary** is not apt because we're not talking about a simple *opposite*.

Comment: Aren't we?  Being *driven by randomness* runs **contrary** to being *described in strict mathematical formulas*, does it not?

Comment: X is confusing. To the contrary, ... ????

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the phrase I've been looking for.

Comment: @TRomano The following sentence doesn't stand against X as expressed by "it is confusing" but "to talk about evolution as a process driven by randomness". I'm sorry if I had formulated the question badly but the sentence RaceYouAnytime suggests is the style how I would  convey the idea in my native language.

Comment: @Probably:  You asked for a phrase to replace the bolded phrase in your paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

> People think widgets are available only in green. **Actually**, they're
>   also available in blue and red.
>
> People think widgets are available only in green. **In actuality**, they're
>   also available in blue and red.

**Actually** is conversational.  **In actuality** is formal.

You could also say:

> ..., **whereas** they're actually available in blue and red as well.

Either will do as a replacement for your  <sup>unidiomatic</sup> **In reverse**.

You could also say **misleading** instead of **confusing**.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a phrase that would include that would express it's the right opposite.

Comment: It *does* express the idea that "the correct idea is as follows..."

Comment: Sure, that's not what I asked for, though. But thanks for this paraphrase.

Comment: You're going n circles, Probably.